# vaadin 14+ - charts - change drillup button text

Tags: highcharts, vaadin, vaadin14

How do I change the text of the drillup button in a chart?
E.g. to translate it?

Example: How to change the Text of "Back to hauptserie"

[image]

Comment: Hi @thi gg, I don't know vaadin, but in basic Highcharts you can set the text through `lang.drillUpText`. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e0h8fmgb/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.drillUpText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text can be set via Lang object using Lang#setDrillUpText.

```
    Lang lang = new Lang();
    lang.setDrillUpText("Zurück zur Hauptserie");
    ChartOptions.get().setLang(lang);
```

https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.3.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/Lang.html#setDrillUpText(java.lang.String)

However in Vaadin 14 the Lang object is not supported. This improvement came post Vaadin 14. Chart version 21.0.9 however is known to work with Vaadin 14, and has the support for Lang object.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts-flow</artifactId>
        <version>21.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```